# How to use pipe in ts not HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I adding text into html element from ts

like this

```
this.legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

this will create html like

```
<text>Data will come here</text>
```

I want to use pipe to convert this data into some form
how can I do that from ts code ?

and as I am creating this HTML dynamically I cannot use pipe like this

```
<text>{{Data will come here | pipename}} </text>
```

I am looking for somethig like

```
this.legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) { return d; }).applypipe('pipename');
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. I'm having hard times understanding what your'e looking for.

Comment: is this fine now ? @MorKadosh

Comment: please add your fully typescript code.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First import your pipe in component. And then use your pipe in your component. Like this..

**pipe.ts**

```
/**
 * filter checkbox list
 */
@Pipe({ name: 'filter', pure: true })
export class FilterPipe{
  transform(items: any[], args: any): any {
    let filter = args.toString();
    if(filter !== undefined && filter.length !== null){
        if(filter.length === 0 || items.length ===0){
            return items;
        }else{
            return filter ? items.filter(item=> item.title.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : items;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**component.ts** (Use in your typescript code)

```
const filterPipe = new FilterPipe();
const fiteredArr = filterPipe.transform(chkArray,txtSearch);
```

**xyz.html** (Use in your html file)

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="todo for todos | filter:'txtsearch'"> {{todo.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: my question is diffrenet how to use this pipe in javascript or typescript code but not in html

Comment: my answer is also use pipe in typescript..Not, use in HTML

Comment: `pure: true` is default... (https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes)

Comment: Shouldn't the pipe be injected inside the constructor?

Answer (score 29):

**import pipe in the component**

```
import { PipeName } from './pipename'
```

**include it in the provides**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pipe-using-component',
    templateUrl: './pipe-using-component.html',
    providers: [
        PipeName
    ],
})
```

**inject it in the constructor**

```
export class PipeUsingComponent {
  constructor(private pipeName: PipeName)
   }

   var requiredResult = this.pipeName.transform(passvalue);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If Pipename is your custom pipe then if you want to use the same in your ts file then you can use below code

```
import {Pipename} from './pipename';

Pipename.prototype.transform(arguments);//this is how u can use your custom pipe
```

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: You would circumvent the `constructor` though, if that were used in the pipe Class, and who knows what `@Pipe` might add?

Answer (score 6):

In your .ts

```
import {YourPipe} from '/pipePath';


let value = new YourPipe().transform(param);
```

Comment: YES! It really is this easy!

Answer (score 0):

I have to use it on multiple methods so I declared a property with its type: `PipeName`.

```
private pipeName: PipeName;
```

Then in constructor.

```
constructor() {
    this.pipeName = new PipeName();
}
```

In case of any service injection.

```
constructor(
    private anotherService: AnotherService
) {
    this.pipeName = new PipeName(anotherService);
}
```

Using pipe to transform anywhere in .ts

```
this.pipeName.transform(value, format);
```

Example

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalizedDatePipe } from '../../../pipes/localized-date.pipe';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'edit-appointment',
    templateUrl: './edit-appointment.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./edit-appointment.component.css']
})
export class EditAppointmentComponent implements OnInit {
    startDate: string;
    localizeDatePipe: LocalizedDatePipe;

    constructor(
        private translateService: TranslateService
    ) {
        this.localizeDatePipe = new LocalizedDatePipe(this.translateService);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.startDate = this.localizeDatePipe.transform('2021-04-08T07:30:00Z', 'd/M/yyyy, h:mm a');
    }
}
```