# How to use translate pipe in typescript instead of template in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I've a requirement where I need to use `translate` pipe of Angular inside typescript logic.

I've seen this question: [How to use pipe in ts not HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653630/how-to-use-pipe-in-ts-not-html/50693592)

I checked this link also: [Translate your Angular App with Pipes](https://malcoded.com/posts/translate-your-angular-app-with-pipes/)

The answer of the above question is working but in that case the pipe was custom made. But in my case `translate` pipe is in-built. It changes languages for texts. My template is like this:

```
<my-component
  [myLabel1]="label1 | translate"
  [myLabel2]="label2 | translate"
  [myLabel3]="label3 | translate"
  [myLabel4]="label4 | translate"
  [myLabel5]="label5 | translate"
  [myLabel6]="label6 | translate">
</my-component>
```

To avoid so many directives I thought of creating an interface and provide all directives as one object such as:

```
<my-component
  [toChildAsInput]="labelObject">
</my-component>
```

I've created an interface: **labelconfig.ts**

```
export interface LabelConfig {
    label1: string;
    label2: string;
    label3: string;
    label4: string;
    label5: string;
    label6: string;
}
```

My typescript is:

```
import { LabelConfig } from './labelconfig';
labelObject:LabelConfig ;
ngOnInit() {
  labelObject.label1="Hello";  // how to apply pipe here
  ...
}
```

I'm stuck here only. How to apply same pipe inside typescript. Please help me. Is it even possible or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you provided your pipe at the module level then simply inject it or provide it at component level in `providers`

```
providers: [ TranslatePipe ]

constructor(private translate: TranslatePipe) {}
```

And simple call `transfom` on the injected instance in component

```
this.data = this.translate.transform(value)
```